# Is it possible to take a web map created via the qgis2web plugin & edit it in Visual Studio Code

Tags: qgis2web, visual-studio-code

After I export a map via qgis2web, is it possible to edit the code and add to it in Visual Studio Code?

If so, how do i open it in VS? is it just the index.html file?

Answer (score 3):

`qgis2web` creates a whole folder containing an `index.html` file and other resources.

These other resources include CSS stylesheets, the map library javascripts, the map data itself, images etc.

The `index.html` contains a head section that loads the resources and then there's likely to be a main "DIV" section that gets the map stuck into it via the map library javascript, triggered by a  section.

Yes, you can edit the `index.html` in a text editor (like VSCode, emacs, vim, notepad...) but be careful not to break it, or the map won't show up. You could do stuff like add text in paragraphs or other HTML. Note that if you save the map again from `QGIS` you'll not get a page with those changes, and will overwrite them if you save to the same location.

Try it!